# Is there a way to create a snowflake external stage, which reads data from s3 access point?

Tags: amazon-s3, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, amazon-s3-access-points

I want to create an external stage in snowflake, which will use S3 access point to access files stored in S3 bucket.
I've started by creating a IAM Role, with attached policy:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:GetBucketLocation",
            "Resource": "<s3_bucket_arn>"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "<s3_bucket_arn>/*",
                "<s3_bucket_arn>"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "s3:DataAccessPointArn": "<s3_access_point_arn>"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The access point has a policy

```json
{
    "Version":"2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "<role_arn>"
        },
        "Action": ["s3:GetObject", "s3:GetObjectVersion"],
        "Resource": "<access_point_arn>/object/*"
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "<role_arn>"
        },
        "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
        "Resource": "<access_point_arn>"
    }]
}
```

In snowflake, I have created the storage integration with sql:

```sql
create storage integration s3ap
    type = external_stage
    storage_provider = s3
    storage_aws_role_arn = '<role_arn>'
    enabled = true
    storage_allowed_locations = ('s3://<access_point_alias>/');
```

Then I've updated Iam role trust policy and created a stage

```sql
create stage test_stage
storage_integration = s3ap
url = 's3://<access_point_alias>';
```

I can list the stage with command `ls @test_stage` and it shows objects in s3 correctly, but when I try to read data with command `select $1 from @test_stage` I get an error `Failed to access remote file: access denied. Please check your credentials`.

I've tried also adding kms privileges, as it was mentioned on this [site](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Troubleshooting-Error-Failed-to-access-remote-file-access-denied-Please-check-your-credentials), to the iam role policy, but the error is still raised.

Am I missing something, or S3 access point cannot be used to create an external stage in snowflake?

Answer (score 1):

S3 access points is not supported yet for external Stages.
You need to use S3 Bucket URL to work with External Tables.